# What do parameters provider_group_name and provider achieve in GroupManager create function when using ArcGIS Python API?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api, grouping, create

The *create()* function in the *GroupManager* module has two parameters; **provide_group_name** and **provider**.

See [API Reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.GroupManager.create)

What is the purpose of these parameters?

I cannot find any documentation relating to their use or description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found more information by using the python help() function on the create() function. These relate to Portal/Enterprise groups and access via LDAP.

> ```
>     --------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------
>     provider_group_name   Optional string. The name of the domain group.
>                           Create an association between a Portal group and an
>                           Active Directory or LDAP group.
>     --------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------
>     provider              Optional string. Name of the provider. Required if the
>                           parameter `provider_group_name` is specified. Example of
>                           use: provider_group_name = "groupNameTest", provider = "enterprise"
> ```